# How can I display error in JSP without a <form:form>

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a jsp page with a `List<Object>` as the `@ModelAttribute`. However, there are no `<form:form>` tags in the page. All I'm doing is print the contents of the `List`.

In my `Controller.java`, I'm binding an error by doing:

`result.rejectValue("", "NOT_LOGGED_IN", "You should Login first") ;`

But since I dont have a form in my jsp, I'm not able to access the error with:

`<form:errors path="" /> <br/>`

Please tell me how to access the error (or what I'm doing wrong).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your controller:

```
model.addAttribute("errors", result.getAllErrors());
```

In your JSP:

```
<c:forEach items="${errors}" var="error">
    <%-- do want you want with ${error} --%>
    <c:out value="${error.defaultMessage}" />
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: @th3an0maly I understood you didn't wanted to use that tag. If you want to use it, you do need a `<form:form />` tag. Why can't you use one?

Comment: Good question. Actually, i figured that out a little late. I've got a `form` in my page now. Thanks anyways.

Comment: smart solution!

Answer (score 3):

Associate global errors this way:

```
result.reject("NOT_LOGGED_IN", "You should Login first") ;
```

You can show the global errors in the jsp :

```
<form:errors cssClass="error" delimiter="&lt;p/&gt;" />
```

Comment: `result.rejectValue("", "NOT_LOGGED_IN", "You should Login first") ;` also registers global errors. I dont think the problem is with that.

Answer (score 0):

for any specific error
set in your code like-

```
model.addObject("errorMsg","username/password failed");
```

And show this error on jsp in this way:

```
<c:out value="${errorMsg}"/>
```

This way you would get your error on jsp.

Comment: in your model, put spring jsr 303 validation. and in resource properties file put the field and error key values.                        And check in your code like -                                            if(result.hasErrors())

Answer (score 0):

there's a way to reference the error like

instead of

```
<form:form commandName="object">
     <form:errors path="field"/>
</form:form>
```

best

Answer (score 0):

Check if Expression Language evaluation is enabled in JSP(By default it is disabled).If not add below code to enable it.

**<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>**